# RDNSS support on Debian 11

Tags: debian, dns, ipv6, resolv.conf

As far as I tried, RDDNS isn't supported natively on Debian 11. I manually installed rdnssd and IPv6 DNS appeared in resolv.conf.

Is RDDNS natively supported on Debian 11 (this means that I would have a problem somewhere) or do I need to in fact install something like rdnssd ?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The default Debian setup with a desktop environment includes Network Manager, and Network Manager handles recursive DNS server discovery itself on connections it manages. This creates problems when combined with `rdnssd` (see [Debian bug 740998](https://bugs.debian.org/740998) for details), and as a result, `rdnssd` conflicts with Network Manager.

Because of the conflict, `rdnssd` can’t be installed by default.

Comment: I forgot to mention this. The Debian 11 used for this testing is an OpenStack image of the system. It is a server version for virtualization. How does it work here ? Thanks

Comment: Where did the OpenStack image come from?

Comment: It is the official image.(https://cdimage.debian.org/images/cloud/bullseye/latest/debian-11-genericcloud-amd64.qcow2)